# Composite query with Orderby in firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

is this a valid query for Firestore?

```
return firestore.collection('users')
            .where('userInfo.gender', '==', "male")
            .where('userInfo.yob','>=',`${data.minYear}`)
            .where('userInfo.yob','<=',`${data.maxYear}`)
            .orderBy('count','asc')
            .limit(5)
            .get()
```

if i want this query to be valid how do i need to structure this?
or how do i add the indexes?

Comment: Is the query not working as it should?  If not, please explain. Be specific about your database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not. If you're doing a greater-than-or-less-than search on one field, you can't then order your results by another field. You're going to have to do the `yob` query first, and then sort the results afterwards.

For more information, you can check out the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries), or this [helpful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI)!